# Update Cell outside CellForRowAt / CellForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am creating a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. The layout setup is pretty fine until I have to **fetch Data from API**. I have to update both my `TableViewCell` data and my `CollectionViewCell` data.

This is how I did the update method:

```
func updateUI() {
        guard vietLottResult.resultModel.count > 0 else {return}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let tableIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            let tableCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tableIndexPath) as! TableViewCell
            
            let date = self.vietLottResult.resultModel[tableIndexPath.row].date
            let dateString = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(date))
            DateFormatter().dateStyle = .short
            DateFormatter().timeStyle = .none
            let localDate = DateFormatter().string(from: dateString)
            tableCell.leftLabel.text = localDate
            
            let colIndexPath = IndexPath.init(item: 0, section: 0)
            let collectionView = tableCell.collectionView
            let colCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: colIndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            colCell.number.text = String(self.vietLottResult.resultModel[collectionView.tag].result[colIndexPath.item])
        }
        
    }
```

Unfortunately, the UI only update the first cell label (both `TableViewCell` and `CollectionViewCell`). I know there must be something wrong with the IndexPath setting but as per my search through all of the similar topic I could not find another answer.

Comment: You have hard coded the index paths? Both index paths are `.init(row:0, section:0)`, that is first row and first section. You should iterate through the data you fetched, using for example a 'while' loop, and then update the collection and table view.

Comment: This is not the way to update table views or collection views. What you'll need to do is to update the model (maybe already done) and then to tell the views to update themselves (`tableview.reloadData()`).

Comment: Not related: `DateFormatter().dateStyle = .short;  DateFormatter().timeStyle = .none; DateFormatter().string(from: dateString)` That's now how it works. You should have `let formatter = DateFormatter(); formatter.dateStyle = .short; formatter.timeStyke = .none`, But not in cellForRow at, but elsewhere because DateFormatter are CPU consumming.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I did it after calling function `fetchData()`. What I posted was just another function called inside the fetch `delegate`

Comment: @Larme I did fixed the lines, tks.

Comment: @Andreas3000 I did change it to 2 for loops. It worked pretty well with all the collectionviewCells inside the first row of TableViewCell but the table only update its first tableViewCell. Sorry i’m typing using my phone so I could not correct my format.